# python mysql understanding parameter bind

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm trying to understand how the bind works when using `%(variable)s`

In my case, my query is: `engine.execute("DELETE FROM testing WHERE test_id in %(ids)s, ids=tuple([1,2,3])))`

If I remove the `(ids)` leaving only `%s` then I get a `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

couple ways of using 'named parameter'. one of them is using dictionary

`engine.execute("SELECT * FROM testing WHERE test_id = %(ids)s, {"ids": ids_value,})`